# C++ program that counts repeated words on a .txt file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a program that counts repeated words on a .txt file and outputs the repeated words and how many time it's repeated. I have a method that counts how many words there are but not the repeated ones. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include "ProcessStatistics.h"

using namespace std;

ProcessStatistics::ProcessStatistics()
{
    //constructor
}

//Finds out how many words are composed by an specific number of         characters.

void ProcessStatistics::Length(std::vector<std::string> ArrayOfWords, int numberOfWords)
{
    cout << "=== COMPUTING WORD S LENGTH ==== " << endl;
    int vectorLength[30] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<20; j++)
        {
            if (ArrayOfWords [i].length()-1 == j)
                vectorLength[j] = vectorLength[j]+1;
        }
    }

    ofstream varlocal;
    remove("WORDS_LENGTH.txt");
    varlocal.open("WORDS_LENGTH.txt");
    if(varlocal.is_open())
    {
        varlocal << "Total: " << numberOfWords << endl;
        for(int i=0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            if(vectorLength[i] != 0)
            {
                varlocal << vectorLength[i] << " W " << i+1 << " CHAR " <<     " % " << setprecision(3) << vectorLength[i]*100/numberOfWords << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    varlocal.close();
```

Comment: And so, what's your question?

Comment: I'm trying to build a program that counts repeated words on a .txt file and outputs the repeated words and how many time it's repeated. So my question is how to output the repeated words

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: try using [unordered_multiset<string>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_multiset/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some sample code that demonstrates word statistics on a text file using `std::map`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using std::ifstream;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::cin;
using std::map;

int main()
{
  static const char filename[] = "my_data.txt";
  ifstream input(filename);
  if (!input)
  {
    cout << "Error opening data file " << filename << "\n";
    return 1;
  }
  map<string, unsigned int> word_data;
  string word;
  while (input >> word)
  {
     if (word_data.find(word) != word_data.end())
     {
       word_data[word]++;
     }
     else
     {
       word_data[word] = 1;
     }
  }
  map<string, unsigned int>::iterator iter;
  for (iter = word_data.begin(); iter != word_data.end(); ++iter)
  {
    cout << iter->second << "\t" << iter->first << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In the above code, the `word` is the key in the `map`.  The word occurrence, count or frequency is the *value* in the `map`.

If the word exists in the `map`, the count is incremented.  If the word doesn't exist, it is added to the `map` with a count of 1.

After reading the file, the statistics are printed, count followed by the word.